# Only update div content if the content is new

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I recently coded this code below that updates my div every 0.5 seconds (500ms) and I want it to only update if you have new content for the box

```
function refreshOnline() {
    $('#toupdate').load('http://frosthotel.co.uk/refreshstats', function() {
        $(this).unwrap();
    });
}

refreshOnline();
setInterval(function() {
    refreshOnline();
}, 500);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `$.get`, `$.post` or `$.ajax` instead of `$.load` and compare the return value on ajax callback function and update if necessary.

```
function refreshOnline() {
    $.get('http://frosthotel.co.uk/refreshstats', function(data) {
        if(data!=$('#toupdate').html()) $('#toupdate').html(data);
    });
}
```